# UWP OneDrive does not support FolderPicker contract on mobile?

Tags: mobile, win-universal-app, onedrive

I am trying to get permission to access an entire OneDrive folder to use as a "working folder" (to automatically load/save files, and to use as a common sync location between devices).

I have used the example here to work with a FolderPicker: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207881

If I use a FilePicker I have the option of "This Device"/"Phone"/"OneDrive", however when using a FolderPicker I only get the option of "This Device"/"Phone".

I haven't seen much documentation around the File/FolderPicker contracts, however it seems that OneDrive only supports the FilePicker contract, not the FolderPicker contract; I don't feel this is correct and I expect I have made a mistake somewhere.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Regards,
Inci

*NB. I have deliberately avoided using the OneDrive API as it adds a layer of complexity that I would rather avoid. Using a FolderPicker allows me to work directly with a StorageFolder which is a consistent and simple approach.*

Comment: I use device and the mobil emulator, I can not found the  "This Device"/"Phone"/"OneDrive".

Comment: Thanks Jayden. This is what I was talking about: https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC820066.png

I have found an answer to my problem - OneDrive just does not support the FolderPicker contract! See this link: https://dev.onedrive.com/SDKs.htm

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive does not support the FolderPicker contract, it only supports FilePickers!

See this link: dev.onedrive.com/SDKs.htm ("FilerPicker SDKs" section-> "Windows" row -> "Documentation" column)